# Trying to bold the first word of each array element

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I'm trying to get a result, of something like this...

```
<b>Run</b> to the shop
<b>Run</b> a business
<b>Run</b> a program
```

Where the first word is in bold. I have an array, and a paragraph element with the class of boldBodyTemplate, and I'm trying to get the array elements to format this way. Here is a prototype of my version.

```
<script>
var verbsToBold = ["Run to the shop", "Run a business", "Run a program"];


for(i=0; i < verbsToBold.length; i++) {
var indexLocation1;
var indexLocation2;
verbsToBold[i].push["<b>"];
indexLocation2 = verbsToBold[i].indexOf[" "];
verbsToBold[i][indexLocation2] = "</b> ";
document.getElementsByClassName("boldBodyTemplate")[0].innerHTML += verbsToBold[i]
}
</script>
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var verbsToBold = ["Run to the shop", "Run a business", "Run a program"];
document.querySelector(".boldBodyTemplate").innerHTML = verbsToBold
  .map(sentence => sentence.replace(/(\w+) (.*)/,"<b>$1</b> $2"))
  .join("<br/>")
```

```html
<div class="boldBodyTemplate"></div>
```

If I copy and paste I get

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, the thing is, the text thats produced when copied and pasted ends up as an unseparated string, and the breaks don't keep? I.e if I copy the list and paste it into a file, it ends up as Run to the shopRun a businessRun a program, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If you copy HOW? Just copy in a way that keeps the break lines or use the array I make without the join

Comment: I get 3 lines if I copy and paste

Comment: Sorted it dude no worries :)

Answer (score 1):

Just fixing your approach with `for` loop. First we take each elements in the array `verbsToBold` and prepend `"<b>"` and then we replace the first space `" "` with `"</b> "` and then append it to your element's innerHTML as you are doing by class name. Notice that I'm using a new variable `verb` for this so that the original data is not changed.

```
var verbsToBold = ["Run to the shop", "Run a business", "Run a program"];

for(i = 0; i < verbsToBold.length; i++) {
    var verb = "<b>" + verbsToBold[i];
    verb = verb.replace(" ", "</b> ");
    document.getElementsByClassName("boldBodyTemplate")[0].innerHTML += verb;
  // console.log(verb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over your array, split the values using a space to get an array of each word, get the first iteration using the key of that array, get the uppercase `.toUpperCase()` and replace the first word, `words[0]` with the upper case using `.replace()`.

```js
const verbsToBold = ["Run to the shop", "Run a business", "Run a program"];
let display = document.getElementById('display');
const toUpper = (arr) => {
  // forEach loop on the array
  arr.forEach((sentence) => {
    // define varaibles for the words array using .split
    let words = sentence.split(' ');
    // get the first word in the array and change to uppercase
    let firstWord = words[0].toUpperCase();
    // replace the first word in the sentence string with the uppercase
    let upper = sentence.replace(words[0], firstWord);
    display.innerHTML += `${upper}<br>`;
    console.log(upper)
  })
}

toUpper(verbsToBold)
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides other answers I was thinking about another approach using CSS:

```js
var verbsToBold = ["Run to the shop", "Run a business", "Run a program"];

var boldBodyTemplate = document.getElementsByClassName("boldBodyTemplate")[0];

for(i=0; i < verbsToBold.length; i++) {

  var output = '<p>';
  var words = verbsToBold[i].split(' ');

  for (j=0; j < words.length; j++) {
    output += '<span>' + words[j] + ' </span>';
  }
  
  output += '</p>';
  
  boldBodyTemplate.innerHTML += output;
}
```

```css
.boldBodyTemplate p span:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="boldBodyTemplate"></div>
```